# Insert a PDF file/Download Link inside a basic HTML page

Tags: html

[enter image description here][1]I am creating a website and I have a pdf page that I wish to insert into my website for people to download.

This is my link below:

```html
<a href="Books/Harry.pdf" download="Harry P">Download the pdf</a>
```

Harry.pdf is inside my Books folder. I already put the Books folder inside my workspace on VSCode. However, my website saids the file is not there.

I have also tried it with my website name as well before the Books/Harry.pdf and it had the same problem. If anyone knows how to just put a pdf link inside a HTML page and how it is done inside VSCode, I would appreciate it.

[image: the file path]

[image: home file]

Comment: Try clearing your cache. It would also be helpful if you showed us the file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<a href="./Books/Harry.pdf" download="Harry">Download</a>
```

Or it will default to the filename on the serverside if you leave it empty, like this:

```
<a href="./Books/Harry.pdf" download>Download the pdf</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should just be this:

```html
<a href="./Books/Harry.pdf" download="Harry">Download</a>
```

It should be the same in VSCode as anywhere else not sure why it isn't working, try setting the `href` as a URL like from google photos, to see if your file is compatible. Another equivalent is to get the url from the file source. So if you own the domain `example.com` your html file would be at `example.com/index.html` and therefore your pdf would be at `example.com/Books/Harry.pdf`. So you could try that if you have a url. It would look like.

```html
<a href="example.com./Books/harry.pdf">Download</a>
```

If you want to provide me with the `.html` file and the `.pdf` file I could probably set it up, but my guess is that is confidential.

As @Spectric said

> Try clearing your cache. It would also be helpful if you showed us the file structure.

That is some good advice.

Answer (score 0):

As per comment you appear to be using relative paths in common parental subfolders e.g. VSyes and Books are both folders together.
With index.html in the former and Harry.pdf in the latter.

Thus your Harry.pdf is a 1st cousin of your index.html in which case you need to use:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" // Should not be needed --> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="download">

    <!-- if you have other canvas elements on this page
       which have been tainted with cross-origin content
       they can become dirty and not readable by html2xxx -->

        <a href = "../Books/Harry.pdf#page=6" download="Cousin Harry">Download Not so Dirty Harry</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**Beware** that since both parental folders are independent of each other that in a production environment although within the same domain (thus not subject to CORS), you may still need to be aware of testing access rights.

if Books is a sub folder in VSyes then remove one dot.